# start postgres as service on windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, service

I am working on windows server and I want to start postgreSQL as service by the following command but it does not work. Could you tell me what is wrong ?

```
sc create postgresql binPath="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_ctl.exe" runservice -w -N "P4" -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data" - start auto
```

### UPDATE

I succedeed to create the service by running the command

```
pg_ctl.exe register -N PostgreSQL -D "%ProgramData%/db_data" –S auto
```

but when i tried to start it I have the following error message

```
The PostgreSQL service on local computer started and then stopped some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs
```

### UPDATE2

One of my colleague resolved the issue. It was a per'ission issue. I hadn't the permission to start the service. The discussion is closed

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Do you get an error? If yes, what? Does the service not start? If yes, what is the error?

Comment: The usual way to create a Windows service is by using `pg_ctrl register ...` rather than `sc`

Comment: it does not give an error but print the help command and does not start the service

Comment: Then apparently your command line for `sc` is incorrect.

Comment: I succeeded runing the command pg_ctl.exe register -N PostgreSQL -D "%ProgramData%/db_data" –S auto